# How do you pass self to class_eval in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working on a metaprogramming task, where I'm trying to use a single method to define a polymorphic association in the calling class, while also defining the association in the target class.  I need to pass in the name of the calling class to get the association right.  Here's a snippet that should get the idea across:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :join_models, :dependent=>:destroy
end

class JoinModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_class
  belongs_to :entity, :polymorphic=>true
end

module Foo
 module ClassMethods
   def acts_as_entity
      has_many :join_models,  :as=>:entity, :dependent=>:destroy
      has_many :some_classes,  :through=>:join_models

      klass = self.name.tableize
      SomeClass.class_eval "has_many :#{klass}, :through=>:join_models"
   end
  end
end
```

I'd like to eliminate the `klass=` line, but don't know how else to pass a reference to `self` from the calling class into `class_eval`.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string parameters will be interpreted in the current context, so you're free to call `self.name` there, or `name` directly:

```
SomeClass.class_eval "has_many :#{name.tableize}, :through=>:join_models"
```

If instead of doing an eval on a string you were using a block, note that `class_exec` is a variation on `class_eval` that allows you to pass parameters naturally. So:

```
SomeClass.class_exec(name.tableize.to_sym) do |klass|
  has_many klass, :through=>:join_models
end
```

It is new to 1.8.7, so you'll need to `require 'backports/1.8.7'` if in 1.8.6.

Note: I'm assuming you need to eval at all, because in your particular example, you can call that method directly, no?

```
SomeClass.has_many name.tableize.to_sym, :through=>:join_models
```

Comment: Great answer, I learned a couple new tricks - thanks.  Your "Note" was the better solution - I had overlooked calling SomeClass.has_many, but knowing about class_exec is helpful as well.